# htaccess redirect 301 keeping id

Tags: .htaccess

i would like redirect permanent 301 :

```
https://www.toto.com/index.php?id=4
```

to

```
https://www.toto.com/?id=4
```

this could be fine ? =>

```
RewriteRule index.php?id=([0-9]+)$ /?id=$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Thanks !

Comment: Do you just want to remove `/index.php` for all URIs?

Comment: yes ! it's for seo, remove index.php but keep all different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match Query String i.e. `?` and part after that in `RewriteRule`.

You can use following rule to remove `index.php` from all paths but keep query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```